# authorized views versus row level security versus complete isolation

Tags: google-bigquery

Hello everyone I have a difficult situation:

How to restrict access to a single data perimeter in a BigQ table for use case layer. Which strategy is best?
Details – The BigQuery warehouse is 76 GB data (annual 20% growth). The reporting/ visualization tool shall be MS Power BI. We want to restrict access of a Italy user to only see Italy data and UK user to only see UK data.

Options considered -

Authorized Views with CONTROL tavle - create and mantain users i project; hard and not scalable

Filtering Views or tables (Complete Isolation Methodology) - create individual views for all countries

BigQ Row Level Security Using “Grant” (Native Methodology) - published in July and very fresh; but we can use grant and apply it to a AD group.

Success criteria - ease of implementation; high perforance with PBI dashboard; ABAC - Attribute based access on rows and scalability to other projects.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you define schema of table too? also which column defines data belong to which country

Comment: Sure; here is the schema - bq load \
--source_format=CSV \
mydataset.mytable \
./myfile.csv \
countrr:STRING,sales:FLOAT,year:STRING

Comment: Comumn countrr contains the country codes